# Get Width and Height of one row in RecycleView - Android

Tags: java, android, height, width

I'm creating `RecycleView` with some items. So I need to get the width and height of the one row of `RecycleView`

Here I'm creating `RecycleView`:

```
    RecyclerView rvSmetki = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvArtikli);
    rvSmetki.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3););
    rvSmetki.setAdapter(new ArtikliAdapter(this));

    // Here I want to get width and height....
```

And this is my ArtikliAdapter:

```
public class ArtikliAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtikliAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static Context context;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Artikl> artikliList;

    public ArtikliAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        artikliList = LogInActivity.getArtiklList();
    }

    @Override
    public ArtikliAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artikli_row, parent, false);
        return new ArtikliAdapter.ViewHolder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArtikliAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Artikl currentArtikl = artikliList.get(position);

        holder.tvNaziv.setText(currentArtikl.getNaziv());
        holder.tvCena.setText("Цена: " + currentArtikl.getProdaznaCena());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return artikliList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private RelativeLayout rlArtikl;
        private TextView tvNaziv;
        private TextView tvCena;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rlArtikl = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlArtikl);
            tvNaziv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNaziv);
            tvCena = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCena);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I get width and height of one row?

Comment: Hi, Did you solved the problem yet? I got return value 0.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
 .....
    holder.itemView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            int cellWidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();// this will give you cell width dynamically
            int cellHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();// this will give you cell height dynamically

        }
    });
  .....
}
```

I hope this will help you!!

Comment: It returns 0. But actually i want to get width and height in Activity, not in Adapter...

Comment: Use interface to send this data back into activity

Comment: Yes, It return 0. Not work @AmrutBidri. Can you explain more detail/

Comment: This will return 0. The correct way is to manually measure the View first. Then fetch the width and height.
`view.measure(
             View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recyclerViewWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
             View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));`

Original and full answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38765295/4344964

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Comment: It depends on the device, so better not to use it. I've seen it working in a pixel but not in a Sony Experia.

Comment: Use a ViewTreeObserver inside viewholder and get the height, if you get height 0.