# How to get the height of recyclerview item in "onBindViewHolder"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The height of RecyclerView item is **not fixed**,i need to set the background image for every item,so I want to get the  height of recyclerview's item to resize the Image,but the  `itemView.getHeight()` always return 0 in `onBindViewHolder`.

I have tried searching for many questions or articles, but I still can't get a good solution.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Short**

Measure the View manually

```
view.measure(
             View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recyclerViewWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
             View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

and get the height with `view.getMeasuredHeight()`

**Background**

A view will return a valid value for `View.getHeight()`only after it has been measured. The measuring itself will automatically happen by the system when the view is about to be displayed on screen.

When Android wants to display the layout, it will recursively call the `view.layout()` function for each view in the view tree. Each Parent tells its children the constraints they might have (width/height) and ask them to `view.measure()` themselves. As a result, the view will store the measured values *BASED* on the constraints in designated members (MeasuredHeight/Width). Note that at this point `view.getMeasuredHeight()` will hold the value while `view.getHeight()` will still be invalid. `view.getHeight()` will only return a valid value once the view has an actual height in the UI hierarchy.

**Recap**

So, to know the height of a view element, before it has been measured and laid out by the system, we will need to invoke the `view.measure()` function manually.

The measure function expects 2 parameters which derived from the view LayoutParams + the parent constraints.

In the above code sample, we are measuring the view forcing its width to be **EXACTLY** the width of the parent (the RecycleView), and the height is not limited.

Comment: It is returning 0 for the first time.On scrolling it is returning values.Is there any way out?

Comment: How you know the `recyclerViewWidth` in `onBindViewHolder`?

Answer (score 18):

I suggest that you define multiple layout files with the expected heights and inflate them according to some criteria in your data set.

```
ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
  if(some condition){
    //inflate layout 1
  }else{
    //inflate layout 2
 }
```

or as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200896/how-to-find-the-width-of-the-a-view-before-the-view-is-displayed): you can get the measurements while initializing the view holder

```
itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = itemView.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: ViewHolder does not have `getMeasuredHeight()` or `getMeasuredWidth()` methods.

Comment: He probably means viewholder.itemView

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
view.post(() -> {
   int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
   int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

using this code to get recycler view's item height:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
         ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //don't forget remove this listener
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        //get item height here
        int itemHeight = v.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### MyViewHolder.kt

With the `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` method, the height value is obtained before the TextView is drawn. And then save it in a member variable.

The key is to **modify the UI inside and outside the implementation of the listener** so that there are no rendering problems (when the views are redrawn).

That is, you shoud use the getter inside the listener and; the setter inside and outside the listener.

```
companion object {

    var maxHeight: Int = 0
   
    fun create(mContext: Context): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_answer, null)

        updateLayout(view)

        view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {

            if (view.myTextView.height > maxHeight)
                maxHeight = view.myTextView.height

            updateLayout(view)

        }

        return MyViewHolder(mContext, view).apply {
            setIsRecyclable(false)
        }
    }

    fun updateLayout(view: View) {
        if (maxHeight != 0 && view.myTextView.height != maxHeight) 
            view.myTextView.height = maxHeight
    }
    

}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134260/5279996)